# Why "finally" doesn't work when PermissionError occurs?

Tags: python

### Problem :

Before running my code, I've used `chmod -w log.txt` and expect to see response of finally block.
However, it just output error info without "f has been closed" in finally block.

### Code:

```
f = open("log.txt", "w")
try:
    f.write("Hello, World!")

finally:
    f.close()
    print("f has been closed")
```

### Output:

[image]

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Because it fails on open, not in the try block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that throws the exception is the `open` call, not the `write`. And the `open` call is outside the `try`, therefore `try-finally` is never even reached, the code crashes before it.

Solution: move the `open` into the `try` as well.